# How do NoSQL (MongoDB) search for something quickly?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question (please move if it isn't).

I was wondering how NoSQLs like MongoDB search for items. As I understand it, NoSQL is merely a database that is NOT SQL (no actual structure). I'll use MongoDB since that's the only type I've had experience with dealing. In the case of MongoDB, collections (instead of tables) that store items in json format.

SQL has columns we can search and sort by. Using json format to store items though, would it not need to do a step like ***parse*** or ***json_decode*** to take out the item and compare thereby, slowing down the request?

Appreciate any info in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every item location of the NoSQL table is stored in HashMap against the hash of primary key. So, it retrieves the data very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken if you think, that the *external representation* as JSON implies the internal data format. (Just as the display as a "table" does not imply anything about the internal structures of a SQL database.)

Fortunately, mongodb is open source, so you can just look into https://github.com/mongodb/mongo